# Joining/Merging two tables to create a third table in SQL

Tags: sql, sybase

I have 2 different tables which look something like the following:

```
--------Table 1---------------------------------------------------------
Cat1           Cat2          Cat3        Value1
a                             d1           13
b              e1                          13
a              e2             d1           13
c                             d2           13
a              e1                          13
a                             d1           13
--------Table 2 -------------------------------------------------
Cat1           Cat2           Cat3       Value2    
a              e2             d1           113
c                             d2           132    
a                             d1           134
a                             d1           131
b              e1                          113
a              e1                          133
```

The Cat1 and Cat2 for above tables are same but might not be in same order. I want to combined both tables above so that desired table looks like following:

```
--------Desired Table---------------------------------------------------------
Cat1           Cat2          Cat3        Value1      Value2
a                             d1           13        134 
b              e1                          13        113
a              e2             d1           13        113
c                             d2           13        132
a              e1                          13        113
a                             d1           13        134
```

I am using apparently an older version of sybase.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this one (from my ANSI SQL experience):

```
    SELECT a.cat1,
           a.cat2,
           a.cat3,
           a.value1,
           b.value2
    FROM tab1 a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT cat1,
              cat2,
              cat3,
              max(value2) value2
       FROM tab2
       GROUP BY cat1,
                cat2,
                cat3) b ON a.cat1 = b.cat1
    AND a.cat2 = b.cat2
    AND a.cat3 = b.cat3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
INSERT INTO table3 (Cat1,Cat2,Cat3,Value1,Value2)
SELECT t1.Cat1, t1.Cat2, t1.Cat3, t1.Value1, t2.value2
FROM table1 as t1, table2 as t2
where t1.Cat1 = t2.Cat2
```

Comment: Do you mean t1.Cat1 = t2.Cat1? If this is the case then why don't we need any condition on Cat2 and Cat3 between tables t1 and t2. Also above looks like an inner join and it does not work with conditions on Cat1, Cat2, Cat3.